# tkinterのbuttonでmessageboxのような動作をさせたい

Tags: python3, tkinter

python初学者です。
tkinterのButtonを使って、クリックするボタン(OK, cancel)によって異なる変数(True,False)を格納した後ウインドウが消えるプログラムを作成しようとしています。動きとしてはmessageboxのaskokcancelのような動きです。
普通であればmessageboxを使う所なのですが、ハイパーリンクをダイアログ中に入れたかったので、以下のようにButtonで作成しております。
本題ですが、このソースだと戻り値のbuffがどちらのボタンを押してもTrueのまま返ってきてしまいます。destroyした時点でBooleanVarへの格納は出来なくなってしまうようです。
destroyを消すと戻り値はボタンに応じて変わるようになるのですが、当然フレームが消えません。
これらを共存させるよい方法がありましたらご教示願えませんでしょうか。

Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (32-bit)
Tcl/Tk 8.6
です。

```py
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

def hyperlink(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(event.widget.cget('text'))

def program_start():
    root.destroy()
    return lambda : buff.set(True)

def program_quit():
    root.destroy()
    return lambda : buff.set(False)

root = tk.Tk()
buff = tk.BooleanVar()
buff.set(True)

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=r'https://google.co.jp',fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
lbl.pack()
lbl.bind("<Button-1>", hyperlink)
tk.Button(root, text = 'OK', width=10 , command = program_start).pack()
tk.Button(root, text = 'cancel', width=10 , command = program_quit).pack()

root.mainloop()

print (buff.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

[リファレンス](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)を見る限り、そもそもコールバックはラムダ式を返すようなものではないようですが・・・。

解決策としては、`set`した後`destroy`するというのではダメでしょうか？

```
def program_start():
    buff.set(True)
    root.destroy()

def program_quit():
    buff.set(False)
    root.destroy()
```

それから

> destroyを消すと戻り値はボタンに応じて変わるようになる

について、destroyを消すと言うのが`root.destroy()`をコメントアウトすることと等価であると仮定して、`set`しているコードは単にラムダ式の一部として返ってるだけなのであり得ないのでは？実際手元では再現しません。

Comment: 上の方法で解決しました。色々調べている際にラムダ式を使って似たような事をやっている資料を多く見つけたもので・・・

Comment: もう一点、destroyを消すと～というのは、書洩らしでしたが、`root.destroy()`をコメントアウトした後に、`command = program_start`の後に()を付けた場合の話でした。

Answer (score 0):

クラス化しての再利用なら、こういった書き方もできるかなと思います。

```py
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

class MsgBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.ret = False
        lbl = tk.Label(self.root, text=r'https://google.co.jp',fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
        lbl.pack()
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", self.hyperlink)
        tk.Button(self.root, text = 'OK', width=10 , command = lambda: self.root_exit(True)).pack()
        tk.Button(self.root, text = 'cancel', width=10 , command = lambda: self.root_exit(False)).pack()

    def hyperlink(self,event):
        webbrowser.open_new(event.widget.cget('text'))

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def root_exit(self,state):
        self.ret = state
        self.root.destroy()

    def get(self):
        return self.ret

msg_box = MsgBox()
msg_box.start()
print(msg_box.ret)
```